# Citation order is corrupted by figures and tables

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I'm already finishing my dissertation and I have to cite all the figures I add. I'm also adding tables with `\includegraphics` adding its cite in both cases (figures and tables) inside `\caption` just as, for example:

```
\caption{xxxxxx \cite{xxxx}}
```

The problem comes when I compile it and the order of citations is completely wrong. What I want is to order my references according to its order of appearance. I have already been trying to find out a solution on this web and, while I just had figures, I used the package "notoccite" and it worked.

A bit later, I started adding tables, I don't know if that's the cause, but my bibliography went back to its wrong order. Now "notoccite" is not working anymore for me.

I've tried using `\ignorecitefornumbering` and `\caption[xxx]{xxx \cite{ref}}` and it is still not working.

I've even modified the `\bibcite` lines in my .aux to set it properly but I don't know if I can compile my pdf without changing that .aux file.

I really need help with this because I have already run out of ideas.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Normally, `notoccite` or `\caption[<caption without citation>]{<caption with \cite>}` should both avoid wrongly sorted citations due to `\tableof...` commands. If both of these don't work for you any more, maybe the problem lies elsewhere? Unfortunately, it is incredibly hard to near impossible to say something useful here without having seen a short example document that reproduces the wrong sorting you are seeing.

Comment: The order of cites is the order in which the \cite{...} is read, not the order in which the cite appear in the PDF.  As floats can float, even without table of contents or with moewe's  fixes, the order of the cites could be changed in the PDF.  Others possible necessary fixes: (1) control the float positions (2) Avoid cites in captions (3) if you are allowed to do,  order references alphabetically  (a matter of taste, but  imho, the best even without this problem).